# Need a list of clients either parent or child; List.Any in Selection.Contains

Tags: vb.net, linq, ienumerable

I need a list of clients where either the client is selected or the client's parent is selected. So I want a list that includes the whole family where the parent is selected.

So I want all items from ClientList where either the ClientList.ParentNum or the ClientList.ClientNum is present in the SelectedList.ClientNum.

```
   Dim ClientList As New List(Of ClientList.Client)
    'add a parent
    ClientList.Add(New ClientList.Client With {.ClientNum = "1234"})
    'add a child
    ClientList.Add(New ClientList.Client With {.ClientNum = "1240", .ParentNum = "1234"})
    'add more clients
    ClientList.Add(New ClientList.Client With {.ClientNum = "0400"})
    ClientList.Add(New ClientList.Client With {.ClientNum = "0500"})
    ClientList.Add(New ClientList.Client With {.ClientNum = "0600"})

    'select one or more clients
    Dim SelectedList As New List(Of ClientList.Client)
    SelectedList.Add(New ClientList.Client With {.ClientNum = "1234"})
    SelectedList.Add(New ClientList.Client With {.ClientNum = "0400"})

    'get ClientList.Any that includes both the parents and their children
    Dim printlist As List(Of ClientList.Client) = _
        ClientList.Any(Function(x) SelectedList.Contains( _
                           Function(y As ClientList.Client) y.ClientNum = x.ClientNum _
                               Or y.ClientNum = x.ParentNum)).tolist
```

So here I should get 3 clients from the ClientList as a PrintList. Clients included would be 1234, 1240 and 0400.

Of course this isn't working as the syntax is garbled but I'm not sure how to get the list I need. Can you help?

> Here is the compile error: Overload resolution failed because no
>   accessible 'Contains' can be called with these arguments:
>       'Public Function Contains(item As PrintOrgs.ClientList.Client) As Boolean': Lambda expression cannot be converted to
>   'Print_Taxes.PrintOrgs.ClientList.Client' because
>   'Print_Taxes.PrintOrgs.ClientList.Client' is not a delegate type.
>       Extension method 'Public Function Contains(value As PrintOrgs.ClientList.Client) As Boolean' defined in
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable': Lambda expression cannot be converted to
>   'Print_Taxes.PrintOrgs.ClientList.Client' because
>   'Print_Taxes.PrintOrgs.ClientList.Client' is not a delegate type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; I just needed the right functions. Exists returns a boolean and Findall returns the items.

```
Dim printlist As List(Of ClientList.Client) = _
    ClientList.FindAll(Function(x) SelectedList.Exists( _
    Function(y) y.ClientNum = x.ClientNum Or y.ClientNum = x.ParentNum)).ToList
```